LaTeX inside HTML tags in a Markdown file running in VSCode is not working
The title describes my problem. This is my markdown file:
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">Minutos</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Proc. 1</th>
      <th>Proc. 2</th>
      <th>Proc. 3</th>
      <th>Utilidad unitaria</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$Prod_1$</td>
      <td>$10$</td>
      <td>$6$</td>
      <td>$8$</td>
      <td>$2$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$Prod_2$</td>
      <td>$5$</td>
      <td>$20$</td>
      <td>$10$</td>
      <td>$3$</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

And the preview in VSCode looks like this:

Is there any compiler for VSCode that can render LaTeX inside HTML tags within markdown files?
